# Why does strpos, position, charindex return 1 when empty substring is passed

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Why do all three of these return a value of 1 in redshift?

`select strpos('X', '')`
`select position('' in 'X')`
`select charindex('', 'X')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the empty string is the very first part of all strings.

Comment: Very Zen.  (Extra words to defeat minimum comment length requirement.)